# My employer refuses to give me a w4 to change my withholdings

Tags: united-states, unprofessional-behavior, taxes

My employer refuses to give me a w4 form because they are mad because i claimed a workmans compisation

Comment: What is a w4 form?

Comment: @solarflare https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf

Comment: the form that is used to determine how much taxes to deduct from his wages

Answer (score 7):

You don't need your employer to furnish you with a W-4. You can download it directly from the IRS website. Your employer (in most cases) is required to submit the new W-4 to the IRS.

https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf

https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc753

Comment: The author does require data necessary to fill out the form though.  The fact the company is not providing one could be an indication proper withholding was withheld.  Claiming workman's compensation isn't a legitimate excuse not to provide a tax form the company is legally required to provide.